# cordova back button event conflicting with browser history

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router

I am making a cordova app, using angularjs and ui-router , the problem is when i use the cordova back button event ,my app doesn't go to the previous page, but if i comment the back button event everything works fine , i want to track the back button event but its seems not to work for me , i tried the below code also doesn't seems to help me.

```
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
      }, true);
```

please help me with the issue

Answer (score 0):

e.preventDefault() as it's name suggests prevents the default behaviour. Therefore you stay on the same page.
If you want to control route switches / state switches imho it's better to listen for the stateChangeStart event. There you can also prevent state changes and you have the extra bonus of knowing which state it came from and where it's going.